# Update the same record by different client in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, delphi, sql-server-2008, delphi-2010

[image]

I am developing an application in Delphi-2010 using SQL Server 2008 R2 in network Mode.

My problem is that in certain cases, multiple clients open the same record for update.
The first client can update the record but the others can't because SQL SERVER can't find the record in question because it has been modified. The application should allow the 2 updates without informing the client.

The table contains many fields nd' the client can update anyone of it for that am not using SQL statement nd' am using UPDATEBATCH().

```
// Press UPDATE
procedure TarticleEditForm.saveButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if (articleCode.Text <> '') AND (counter.Text <> '') AND (articleLabel.Text <> '') AND      (tbCombo.Text <> '') AND (griffeCombo.Text <> '') then begin
      ADOArticleFind.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM article WHERE ID<>''' + ADOArticle.FieldByName('ID').Value + ''' AND article=''' + articleCode.Text + ''' AND mode=''' + modeCombo.Text + ''' AND counter=''' + counter.Text + '''';
      ADOArticleFind.Open;
      // UPDATE
      if ADOArticleFind.RecordCount = 0 then begin
           // SET Date Modification
           ADOArticle.FieldByName('dateModification').Value := Now;
           ADOArticle.FieldByName('modifiePar').Value := mainForm.user;
           ADOArticle.UpdateBatch();
           // Update ArticleColor/ArticleTissu tables
           ADOArticleColor.SQL.Text := 'UPDATE articleColor SET article=''' + articleCode.Text + ''', mode=''' + modeCombo.Text + ''', counter=''' + counter.Text + ''' WHERE article=''' + tmpArticleCode + ''' AND mode=''' + tmpMode + ''' AND counter=''' + tmpCounter + '''';
           ADOArticleColor.ExecSQL;
           ADOArticleTissu.SQL.Text := 'UPDATE articleTissu SET article=''' + articleCode.Text + ''', mode=''' + modeCombo.Text + ''', counter=''' + counter.Text + ''' WHERE article=''' + tmpArticleCode + ''' AND mode=''' + tmpMode + ''' AND counter=''' + tmpCounter + '''';
           ADOArticleTissu.ExecSQL;
           // create event log
           mainForm.ADOUser.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE online=1 AND editArticleEvent=1 AND username<>''' + mainForm.user + '''';
           mainForm.ADOUser.Open;
           while not mainForm.ADOUser.Recordset.EOF do begin
                mainForm.ADOMainEventLog.Insert;
                mainForm.ADOMainEventLog.FieldByName('event').Value := 'Article modifié: ' + designationCombo.Text + ' ' + saisonCombo.Text + ' ' + articleCode.Text + '-' + modeCombo.Text + counter.Text + ' de ' + griffeCombo.Text;
                mainForm.ADOMainEventLog.FieldByName('eventFrom').Value := mainForm.user;
                mainForm.ADOMainEventLog.FieldByName('eventTo').Value := mainForm.ADOUser.FieldByName('username').Value;
                mainForm.ADOMainEventLog.FieldByName('eventType').Value := 'editArticleEvent';
                mainForm.ADOMainEventLog.UpdateBatch();
                mainForm.ADOUser.Next;
           end;
           // Finish
           Self.Close;
      end
      else begin
           MessageBox(Application.Handle, 'Cet article existe déja.', 'GET© Driver', MB_ICONWARNING);
           articleCode.SetFocus;
      end;
 end
 else
      MessageBox(Application.Handle, 'Champs obligatoire(s) manquant(s).', 'GET© Driver', MB_ICONWARNING);
end;
```

Comment: In this case you need to be more specific. This is not a Delphi related question, It's more a architecture question. Why are your users working on the same record at the same time?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information before anyone can give you advice, and most importantly you need to clearly define what should happen in this scenario. Should the application allow the second update? Not allow it? Inform the user? Queue the updates and apply them asynchronously in order? And why exactly can't the second update find the row (assuming the primary key has not changed)?

Comment: we assume that we have 2 SQLQuery: SQLQuery1 nd' SQLQuery2. SQLQuery1  nd' SQLQuery2 open a connexion to the record A. SQLQuery1 post update to A. but SQLQuery2 can't.

Comment: the application should allow the 2 updates without informing the client

Comment: this application is for my company. imagine the number of clients

Comment: Check the SQL `where` clause, does your code build the where clause  or is it created by the internal db driver code? This problem can easily happen with optimistic locking, when the where inlcudes all changed fields. Other potential reason: database triggers.

Comment: If you are using a `TDataSetProvider` you should have a look at the property `UpdateMode`. It should be `upWhereKeyOnly` if you want the second update to happen.

Comment: @anismetal You still haven't explained why query 2 cannot find the row that was updated by query 1. What is the primary key of the table and what does a typical UPDATE statement look like? Usually, query 2 would be blocked (hopefully for a few ms) by query 1's update lock, but as soon as the lock is freed then update 2 would happen anyway. If it doesn't, it suggests that the table has no primary key; it has one but the application doesn't use it; or the application is updating the primary key.

Comment: I am not using SQL command (UPDATE ... WHERE) but I am using delphi command : UPDATEBATCH()

Comment: the primary key is UNIQUEIDENTIFIER nd' am not updating it :(

Comment: the table contains 147 fields nd' the client can update any fields for that am not using SQL statement nd' am using UPDATEBATCH();

Comment: @anismetal: Please stop adding comments. Edit your original question and add the details instead, where people trying to help you can easily see them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always prefer to use pure SQL to make stuff happen in databases, instead of relying on the database-abstraction in the datasets/tables.

```
Query1.SQL.Text:= 'UPDATE table1 SET a=:newvalue WHERE A=:oldvalue';
Query1.ParamByName('newvalue').AsString:= '1';
Query1.ParamByName('oldvalue').AsString:= '2';
Query1.Prepare;
Query1.ExecSQL;
```

Using code like this you can set as many concurrent updates to SQL-server as you'd like.

Comment: maybe this is a newbis question but why you are using "Query1.Prepare" ?

Comment: I cant use this because if the Cleint1 update the record with the values in the FORM1, the Client2 will update the record with old value in FORM2 because the new update doesnt affect it.

Comment: @anismetal, A: the prepare is there `just in case` you should not need it, but older Delphi code complains if it's not there. B: The `where` clause makes sure only the right values get updated, you should never do an update without a `where`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you say that you use `updatebatch` I assume that you use TADODataSet (or perhaps TADOTable, TADOQuery).

How ADO builds the update statement is controlled by the recordset property `Update Criteria`. Default value is `adCriteriaUpdCols` which means that the update's where clause compares all modified fields against the old/original value. To make `updatebatch` only use the key columns you can do something like this.

```
ADODataSet1.CommandText := 'select * from SomeTable';

ADODataSet1.Open;
ADODataSet1.Recordset.Properties['Update Criteria'].Value := adCriteriaKey;

ADODataSet1.Edit;
ADODataSet1.FieldByName('SomeColumn').AsString := 'New value';
ADODataSet1.Post;

ADODataSet1.UpdateBatch();
```

The above code for a TADOQuery would look like this.

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select * from SomeTable';

ADOQuery1.Open;
ADOQuery1.Recordset.Properties['Update Criteria'].Value := adCriteriaKey;

ADOQuery1.Edit;
ADOQuery1.FieldByName('SomeTable').AsString := 'New value';
ADOQuery1.Post;

ADOQuery1.UpdateBatch();
```

BTW, `adCriteriaKey` is defined in ADOInt.pas

Comment: there is no properties called 'Update Criteria' for ADOQuery

Comment: @anismetal - It's property of `recordset` look at the updated code for how to use it with TADOQuery.

Comment: Setting it to adCriteriaKey could introduce the risk of overwriting changes made by other users at the same time. IIUC, adCriteriaUpdCols implements optimistic locking. (however this comment is based on my InterBase/dbExpress work)

Comment: @mjn - Yes that will happen. Last one that saves wins. But as I read the question that is the desired behavior.

Comment: @Mikael OMG ! `the application should allow the 2 updates without informing the client` ...